Integrate a sum of trig function under absolute value
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I'm trying to compute an explicit formula for the following integral:
$$
\operatorname{I}\left(n\right) = \int_{\left[0,2\pi\right]^{\,\,n}}\,
\left\vert\rule{0pt}{4mm}\,{\cos\left(x_{1}\right) + \cdots + \cos\left(x_{n}\right)}\,\right\vert{\rm}dx_{1}\dots
{\rm d}x_{n}
$$

It's easy to prove that for $n = 1,2$: $\operatorname{I}\left(1\right) = 4$ and $\operatorname{I}\left(2\right) = 32$.. but from $n = 3$ the calculations became very hard.
It would be nice if $\operatorname{I}\left(n\right) = 2^{3n - 1}$, but I don't know how to prove it.
It's also difficult to compute $\operatorname{I}\left(n\right)$ numerically, because the function we are integrating "oscillates" near the value $0\ldots$ and most of numerical methods fail to properly approximate it.

Thank you for any hint/help!

If you find a recursive relationship, it is more likely that the function will not be linear in the exponent and be more like $2^{2^n-n}$ or something similar.

First, some symmetry considerations. Since $\cos x$ takes on the same values $[0,\pi]$ as it does on $[\pi,2\pi]$, we have that
$$\int_{[0,2\pi]^n}\cdots d^nx = 2^n\int_{[0,\pi]^n}\cdots d^nx$$
We still can't integrate as there is more symmetry to exploit. Consider the $k$th variable and the following symmetry
$$\int_{\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^{k-1}\times\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]\times\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^{n-k}}|\cdots + \cos(x_k) + \cdots| d^nx = \int_{\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^n}|\cdots-\cos(x_k)+\cdots|d^nx$$
Since there is no meaningful difference between each of the variables of integration, only the number of variables with flipped signs matters. This gives us way to map each sub "cube" to the corner "cube" attached to the origin. Thus denoting
$$f_k(x) \equiv -\cos(x_1) - \cdots - \cos(x_k) + \cdots + \cos(x_n)$$
we have the following simplification
$$2^n\int_{[0,\pi]^n}|f_0(x)|d^nx = 2^n\int_{\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^n}d^nx\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}|f_k(x)|$$
We can compute the $k=0$ and $k=n$ terms as being
$$2^n\int_{\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^n}|f_0(x)|d^nx = 2^n\int_{\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]^n}|f_n(x)|d^nx = 2n\pi^{n-1}$$
but it is difficult to continue beyond this.

Thank you! This is at least a very interesting step forward.. it would be fantastic to find a recursion for $I(n)$, in order to somehow express $I(n+1)$ as a function of $I(n)$. Anyway, +1.

We can also see that $|f_k(x)| = |f_{n-k}(x)|$ again by simmetry.

@MathRevenge yes but we cannot pull out the factor of $2$ because if $n$ is even, there is no complement of $\frac{n}{2}$

Yeah.. it depends on the parity of $n$. Anyway I suspect that from $n = 3$ the expression of this integral is very ugly compared to the first cases. I'm starting to think there is no closed form unfortunately.
